# Using loadTable with correct types in typescript with p5js

Tags: typescript, p5.js

I am loading a csv file using the p5.js function, loadTable. It seems that its not reading the csv file at all, maybe i am missing something in my approach.

```
  let data: p5.Table;

  p.preload = () => {
    let csv_file: string = "./sample.csv";
    let csv_type: string = "csv";
    let csv_header: string = "header";

    data = (p as any).loadTable(csv_file, csv_type, csv_header);

    console.log("data ", data.getRowCount());
  };
```

It works fine in javascipt as below.

```
let data;

// preload table data
function preload() {
  data = loadTable(
    'sample.csv',
        'csv',
        'header');
}
```

Comment: Here is the complete repo where i played with the idea of loading a csv file, it seems it does not work in typescript. https://github.com/suvirbhargav/p5js-typescript-fusebox. I added the loadTable call in sketch.ts. If loadTable is commented out, the project works fine.

Answer (score 1):

ah, i figure it out. The issue was not related to typescript. It was browser cors policy.

Something like this works fine in typescript + p5.js,

```
p.preload = () => {
    data = (p as any).loadTable("http://127.0.0.1:34568/", "csv", "header");
  };
```

Where i hosted my own csv on a local web server (http://127.0.0.1:34568/) using cpprestSDK. Or even host the file over some url like github and read from there while in development. That worked fine as well.

Other option i found was, browser-sync. https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Local-server#node-http-server-2nd-option. It did worked for some people, for me, chrome still gave cors error from browser-sync.